# How to exclude specific references from deepcopy?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have object which has it's own content (i.e. list of something) and a reference to another object, with which it is linked. How can I exclude the reference to the other object from being deep-copied?

```
from copy import deepcopy
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, content, linked_to):
        self.content = content
        self.linked_to = linked_to

a1 = Foo([[1,2],[3,4]], None)
a2 = Foo([[5,6],[7,8]], a1)

a3 = deepcopy(a2) # <- I don't want there, that a3.linked_to will be copied
# I want that a3.linked_to will still point to a1

a3.linked_to.content.append([9,10])
print a1.content # [[1,2],[3,4]], but I want [[1,2],[3,4], [9,10]]
```

Comment: That's not a weak reference. That's just a normal reference to another object.

Comment: You can implement it yourself by implementing `__deepcopy__` in `Foo`

Comment: That's why it's quoted, just to separate it from other type of reference in context of the question.

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov: then perhaps don't call it a weak reference; just say you want to exclude something in the copy?

Comment: Ok, let's call it 'special', thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your class can implement a `__deepcopy__` method to control how it is copied. From the [`copy` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> In order for a class to define its own copy implementation, it can define special methods `__copy__()` and `__deepcopy__()`. The former is called to implement the shallow copy operation; no additional arguments are passed. The latter is called to implement the deep copy operation; it is passed one argument, the memo dictionary. If the `__deepcopy__()` implementation needs to make a deep copy of a component, it should call the `deepcopy()` function with the component as first argument and the memo dictionary as second argument.

Simply return a new instance of your class, with the reference you don't want to be deep-copied just taken across as-is. Use the `deepcopy()` function to copy other objects:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, content, linked_to):
        self.content = content
        self.linked_to = linked_to

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        # create a copy with self.linked_to *not copied*, just referenced.
        return Foo(deepcopy(self.content, memo), self.linked_to)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a1 = Foo([[1, 2], [3, 4]], None)
>>> a2 = Foo([[5, 6], [7, 8]], a1)
>>> a3 = deepcopy(a2)
>>> a3.linked_to.content.append([9, 10])  # still linked to a1
>>> a1.content
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [9, 10]]
>>> a1 is a3.linked_to
True
>>> a2.content is a3.content  # content is no longer shared
False
```

Comment: how does the memo parameter fall into this? I'm struggling to get my head around how to do this for an arbritrary number of properties I want linked and not linked

Comment: @Rugnir you need to pass it along to other `deepcopy()` calls, nothing else. For every property you need to copy for the return value, call `deepcopy(value_to_copy, memo)`.